# R: tsCV function returns NA

Tags: r, na

I am using the packages "fpp" and "fpp2".

The homework question (question 11(f)) is located at https://otexts.org/fpp2/expsmooth-exercises.html

I've tried to run the following code for tsCV on the ETS model (the same results occur for other models as stated in 11(d)):

> convert *visitors* to time series

`tvis <- ts(visitors)`

> run tsCV on tvis

`e2 <- tsCV(tvis, forecast(ets(tvis),h=24), h=24)`

However, when I run *e2*, all I get are NA values.

> [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
>
> [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
>
> [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
>
> [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

Why is this so?

It works if I used another forecast function instead (e.g. rwf):
`e2 <- tsCV(tvis, rwf, h=24)`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having similar issues with using tsCV with ses

Answer (score 3):

The key word is "function": for its second argument, `tsCV` expect a function that returns a forecast, not actually a forecast. Try this:

```
f  <- function(y, h) forecast(ets(y), h = h)
e2 <- tsCV(tvis, f, h)
```

Comment: thank you
f  <- function(y, h) ses(y,alpha = NULL,h=h,initial="simple")
e2 <- tsCV(ts_data, f, 1)

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is a little old but I thought I would put in something I found while debugging a similar issue.  I'm not sure if ets has similar notes or not.  When using `auto.arima` with `xreg` the response will be of `length(xreg)` regardless of the h specification, as per the function documentation.  My solution was to just slice the mean output for measurement. Also note that you may encounter an error if you specify anything other than (...) for your function input.  Hope this helps

```
forecast_fun <- function(...) {
  x <- auto.arima(y, 
    lambda = 0,
    xreg=xreg) %>% 
  forecast(xreg=xreg, 
    h=h) 
  x$mean <- x$mean[1:h]
  return(x)
}
```